# Flutter - null check operator error in a child that should not be rendered yet

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I made a `Loader` widget which shows a loading indicator if `isLoading = true` and shows a child widget only if `isLoading = false`.

The problem is when I use nullable data in the child, even though `isLoading = true` should prevent the child from being rendered, Flutter still gives me `Null check operator used on a null value` and a red screen.

Example:

```dart
class Example extends StatelessWidget {
  const Example({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String? data = null; // Just an example

    return Loader(
      isLoading: data == null,
      child: Text(data!), // Flutter will parse this even though Loader never attempted to render it
    );
  }
}
```

This is my Loader widget:

```dart
class Loader extends StatelessWidget {
  const Loader({
    Key? key,
    required this.isLoading,
    required this.child,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final bool isLoading;
  final Widget child;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (isLoading) {
      return CircularProgressIndicator();
    else {
      return child;
    }
  }
}
```

*Note: I want the Loader as a wrapper to clean up my code, because my `isLoading`, my Loader and the data are much more complicated.*

Comment: Are you trying to make `child`  nullable on `Loader `?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh No, even in my real code the child in `Loader` is required and non-null

Comment: means you like to test  if the child's child/property is null or not?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, yeah I only want to render the child if its property is non-null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could refactor your `Loader` to use a builder instead:

```
class Loader extends StatelessWidget {
  const Loader({
    Key? key,
    required this.isLoading,
    required this.builder,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final bool isLoading;
  final WidgetBuilder builder;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (isLoading) {
      return CircularProgressIndicator();
    } else {
      return builder(context);
    }
  }
}
```

Then use it like

```
class Example extends StatelessWidget {
  const Example({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String? data = null; // Just an example

    return Loader(
      isLoading: data == null,
      builder: (_) => Text(data!),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Interesting, that solves it. I tried using a builder before but I defined the parameter in Loader like this: `final Widget Function(BuildContext context) builder` instead of using `WidgetBuilder`.

Comment: @mrn that actually should have worked as well. Because a `WidgetBuilder` is defined the same way

Comment: Hmm, I must have done something else wrong before. Oh well, problem solved :)

Answer (score 1):

This happened when try to parse the code, even if that part of code not rendered, because dart null safety policy not accept `!` on a `null` value. So this is not the issue in `Loader` widget, this is inside the child that you try to pass. Try set default value like this:

```
return Loader(
  isLoading: data == null,
  child: Text(data ?? ''), //<--- add this
);
```

Comment: In reality my child uses multiple nullable values with complicated data structures (not just a string), and setting fallbacks for whose would require using constructors with a bunch of parameters. That would look even uglier than an if condition in the parent builder.

Comment: I'll give you an upvote since this technically solves the issue, but not for the purpose of cleaning up the code.

Comment: you have two options for complicated model. you can set default value when you try to use those values (for example when you try to show them) or in your class model make them required and set the default value there.

Comment: That's out of the scope but the reason I can't do that is that my data structures need nullable values for other functionality, and setting defaults for the loader would be messy: for example, one child in a loader uses classes with dates, ID's, maps of JSON data fetched from the backend and some enums. I could take random ones to satisfy flutter but this would add much more junk code in my builder, and it would be nicer to just use `if (dependenciesAreNull) {show loader} else {show child}`, which is what I currently do.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a default value to be shown in the `Text` widget when it's `null` using the `??` like this:

```
  return Loader(
  isLoading: data == null,
  child: Text(data ?? "default data"), 
);
```